# Is there a way to select the transpose option using the keyboard when pasting special in Excel?

Tags: excel, copy-paste

I have to do some copy/pasting every now and then and would find it really convenient if I didn't have to use the mouse to select the transpose option manually when pasting values. I know I can transpose only by clicking shift+F10 and then pressing T, but then it copies formulas and not values like I want. Is there any way to paste values and transposing them?

Thankful for any help I can get!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the paste special menu, the letter underlined in each alternative is the corresponding shortcut key for that alternative. Thanks for pointing that out, @VBasic2008!

So, for my local verison of Excel (Swedish), I could press N to select the transpose option.

Comment: It's the underlined `n` in `Transponera` as it is the underlined `e` in `Transpose` of the default (US) version.

Comment: Oh, I see! I didn't realise the underlined letter was the shortcut. Do you mind writing an answer so that I can accept it and give you some points? @VBasic2008 :)

Comment: You should edit your answer so people can give you votes. Feel free to use the additional information from my comment.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Okay, thank you! I have updated the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the paste special menu, the letter underlined in each alternative is the corresponding shortcut key for that alternative. Thanks for pointing that out, @VBasic2008!

So, for my local versions of Excel (Swedish), I could press N to select the transpose option.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).